from XX seconds value in cell into XXminXXsec
I want to convert my seconds value into x min x seconds
is there any one formula template in one go?

Example : 67 -> 1m7s, 143 -> 2m23s:


I've tried =TEXT(AN3/86400, "mm:ss") the result is 00:30
2try, changed to "mmss" resulting 0030
my mission is to get 30s, how to not remove 0 if there are no minutes and no 2digits (07 sec to 7sec) in my value

Are they purely for showing or do you still want to use these new outputs for calculations?

This task looks simple for the first look only.

Use the following formula to convert seconds to minute & seconds.
=B2/(24*60*60)

Then apply desired time formats m\mss\s to cells. If you want to formatted output then use TEXT() function like-
=TEXT(B2/(24*60*60),"m\mss\s")



Would "m\mss\s" work for durations longer than 60 minutes?

I don't tested that. We may apply different format then.

Surely, "mm:ss" is limited by an hour only. We need to state this as limitation while TS didn't mention >3599.

You could

convert seconds to time: =TIME(0,0,D5:K5)

This is an array formula, if using older versions, please select the range and enter with Control + Shift + Enter


Add a custom number format: [m]"m"ss"s";;0;

[m] is for duration and "m" for literal text
use [m]"m"s"s";;0; to omit leading zero for seconds





If you don't want to use custom number format,
=TEXT(TIME(0,0,D5:K5), "[m]""m""ss""s"";;0;")

Quotes need to be doubled up

More advanced: [<0.000694444]s"s";[m]"m"s"s"  This will only show the Minutes if time is >=60 seconds(i.e. 01:01:30 will become 61m30s, while 00:00:30 will become 30s)

Thank you very much @Chronocidal. I'll remember this option for the next time. We don't need it here ("to not remove 0 if there are no minutes"), right?

Try using the following formula with an IFS() logic inducted within  TEXT() :


• Formula used in cell B1
=LET(
     α, B1,
     δ, α/60,
     Σ, IFS(δ=0,"0",δ<1,"s\s",δ=1,"m\m",1,"m\mss\s"),
     TEXT(α/86400, Σ))


Or, Spill the whole array, no need to fill right.
=LET(
     α, B1:I1, 
     δ, α/60, 
     Σ, IFS(δ=0,"0",δ<1,"s\s",δ=1,"m\m",1,"m\mss\s"), 
     TEXT(α/86400, Σ))


Or, else:


=MAP(B1:K1,LAMBDA(α,
 LET(δ,TEXTSPLIT(TEXT(α /86400,"m:ss"),,":"),
 IF(α,CONCAT(REPT(δ&{"m";"s"},SIGN(δ))),0))))



I am delighted! And this formula can be easily adjusted by replacing "m:ss" with "m:s" if TS needs "67 -> 1m7s" (how it stated) not "67 -> 1m07s".

I can propose the next formula which avoids all kind of leading or trailing zeros:
=LET(t,A1/86400,m,TEXT(t,"m\m:ss"),s,TEXT(t,"s\s"),IF(LEFT(m,1)<>"0",TEXTBEFORE(m,":"),"")&IF(s<>"0s",s,""))


67 --> 1m7s
37 --> 37s
60 --> 1m


Assuming the seconds value is in cell A1, use the following formula:
=INT(A1/60) & " min " & MOD(A1,60) & " sec" 
